# Do you need to install php library if you already installed extension?

Tags: php, mongodb, composer-php

I've successfully been able to perform CRUD operations on a remote MongoDB Server with a PHP script using the instructions on [MongoDB PHP Driver Installation Instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php/)

It was kinda trial-and-error for me to get it to work and I'm not sure the exact sequential steps I took. However, according to my `history` command's output, It looks like I just installed the `mongoDB` driver using `pecl` and then inserted the extension into my `php.ini` file.

I then am able to access all the MongoDB functions in code by using syntax like the following

```
new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime
new MongoDB\BSON\Regex
new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite
```

The instructions state, `"Install the PHP MongoDB Extension before installing the PHP Library for MongoDB"` and then tells you to do `composer require mongodb/mongodb`

Looks like I never installed the library with `composer` and that it all still works.

What is the difference between installing the Extension vs the Library?

Why is this able to work without me installing the library and is there any real disadvantage into me not installing it?

It looks like `pecl` is php's version of `npm`. So, how would `composer` be described then?

Comment: `XAMPP` *implies* that PHP is already installed -- As it stands for: `Apache, MySQL, PHP and Perl` -- As far as the difference between the PHP library and a PHP extension .. It's exactly what it sounds like.  PHP is a `hypertext preprocessor` -- And extensions do just that -- They "extend" the preprocessor to be able to do more things, like connect to a database, etc etc

Comment: And Composer is not an extension .. It's a PHP Library for managing PHP dependencies and projects.

Comment: The MongoDB PHP Library is a high-level extension, it provides similar commands as you have in the Mongo Shell (see https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/). The MongoDB driver is a low-level extension, for your application you would need to write more code, most likely.